# can we convert Debug build APK to release Build without having source code

Tags: java, android, debugging, apk, release

i have a debug mode APK which i need to convert into release Build.
the main issue is i lost source code and keyStore file of that APK.
and app is already on playstore.
so can we change Debug Build to Release Build in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you lose your keys used for signing APKs or App Bundles, you can request a new one. Losing your source code. That's a bit interesting. Don't you use Git? I don't suppose you'd have non-existant version control on a "complex" project. I'm forced to assume your app isn't too complex and could be therefore created from scratch with no trouble... Take better care and make sure to use VC and backup your keys.

Comment: actually this apk is belong to my client who built this from another vendor. so vendor haven't gave him code.my client only have is debug build

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reverse engineering your own app using this tool:

https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

You have to decode your debug apk using:

```
apktool d debug-app.apk
```

And then build again the release apk:

```
apktool b debug-app
```

Then, Sign it with your own keystore.